# CSS: align and wrap text

Tags: html, css

I use the pre tag to load posts into.

I have two issues, when there is a long continues word like 11111111111111, the pre doesn't line break and if i have a complete sentence some of rest of words would break into new line.

this is my issue when pre style is word-break:inherit;
[image]

and this is my issue when pre style is word-break:break-all;
[image]

So, if i used word-break:inherit; then the text would be perfectly wrapped and if i used word-break:break-all; then the long words will line break but the text won't wrap as needed.

any advice what should i do?

this is my html block for that part:

```
            <tr style="background-color: white;">

                <td colspan="2">

                    <pre style="word-break:break-all; border:none; font-size: 13px; font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;">@ep.POST</pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

---EDIT---
I just solved it by using break-word

Comment: And what happened when using `break-word`?

Comment: Also, can you tell what do you mean by `text won't wrap as needed`?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Thanks break-word solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
p {
  word-break: normal | break-all | keep-all;
}
```

PS: Actually it is [Andrius Naruševičius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167953/andrius-narusevicius), whose comment answered the OP. I am adding an answer for googlers.

Answer (score 1):

What about `white-space: pre-line` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/93S5U/